# action helper and routing priority laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

### I have two rules

```
Route::get('this-is-an-awesome-route', 'Ads@getIndex');
Route::controller('ads', 'Ads');
```

### action('Ads@getIndex') renders

```
http://my-awesome-domain/ads
```

### I want

```
http://my-awesome-domain/this-is-an-awesome-route
```

What's the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The second route is rewriting the first route declaration. Let's see:

```
// Ads@getIndex will be called
Route::get('this-is-an-awesome-route', 'Ads@getIndex');

// Ads@getIndex will be called too by native definition
Route::controller('ads', 'Ads');
```

Because of `Route::controller('ads', 'Ads')` is called as latest declaration it will overwrite the previous one. So, you have at least two ways to achieve this task

1. You could create a new function into `Ads` controller just to response to the first route:

   ```
   Route::get('this-is-an-awesome-route', 'Ads@awesome');
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   public function awesome(){
       // do stuff here
   }
   ```
2. Rename the route name for your controller

   ```
   Route::controller('ads', 'Ads', [
       'getIndex' => 'ads.getHome',
   ]);
   ```

   Now your `Route::controller('ads', 'Ads');` will respond to `getHome()` instead `getIndex()` as per renamed route:

   ```
   public function getHome(){
       // do stuff for getIndex() definitions here
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason from **Laravel 4.2** to **Laravel 5** the logic changed a little bit. The line you wrote was working before, you just have to reverse everything as the router isn't processing your code the same way.

### Tested and working solution

```
Route::controller('ads', 'Ads');
Route::get('this-is-an-awesome-route', 'Ads@getIndex');
```

The first route will be overwritten by the second one.